# robot framework three if condition. - not working

Tags: robotframework

I am trying following robot test case but it is not working.

my requirement is:

1. if 'bbb' is equal to 'aaa' than log to console "bbb is equal to aaa" and fail the test case. Don't run next conditions.
2. if 'bbb' is greater than 'aaa' than log to console "bbb is GREATER than aaa" and run next test if condition, if next if condition passes than print "bbb is greater than or equal to max and pass the test case.

how to do this? following script is running all if conditions. please help.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation           TEST aaa, bbb, max
    
Library    SSHLibrary
Library    String
Library    DebugLibrary

*** Variables ***

${aaa}    5
${bbb}    10
${max}    15


*** Test Cases ***

   Test aaa, bbb, max
       [Documentation]     Test aaa, bbb, max
        Run Keyword If    '${bbb}' == '${aaa}'    log    bbb is EQUAL to aaa    Fail
        Run Keyword If    '${bbb}' > '${aaa}'      log    bbb is GREATER than aaa    Pass   
        Run Keyword If    '${bbb}' >= '${max}'      log    bbb is GREATER than max    Pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You define numeric variables but testing as strings.
Only the `Log` keyword would run, the Fail and Pass are ignored.
The test is currently passing without output because none of the conditions are True.

Here is a modified version of you test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     TEST aaa, bbb, max
Library           SSHLibrary
Library           String
Library           DebugLibrary

*** Variables ***
${aaa}            9
${bbb}            10
${max}            15

*** Test Cases ***
Test aaa, bbb, max
    [Documentation]    Test aaa, bbb, max
    Run Keyword If    ${bbb} == ${aaa}    Fail    bbb is EQUAL to aaa test will Fail
    Run Keyword If    ${bbb} > ${aaa}    Log To Console    bbb is GREATER than aaa test will Pass
    Run Keyword If    ${bbb} >= ${max}    Log To Console    bbb is GREATER OR EQUAL than max test will Pass
    Run Keyword Unless    ${bbb} > ${aaa} or ${bbb} >= ${max}    Log To Console    Condition not covered test will Pass
```